# Saber como se llama el objeto del JSON sin saber su nombre

Tags: java, spring-boot

Saber como se llama el objeto del JSON sin saber su nombre

Como puedo saber exactamente como se llama el objeto que contiene el array osea donde dice `files,grupo,cargo` sin saber
su nombre ya que podria obtener diferentes

```
{"files":[{"tipo":"zip","dt":"4010","id":"35","grup":"015"}]}
{"grupo":[{"id":"19","idg":"12"}]}
{"cargo":[{"ar":"9","id":"1","rol":"1"}]}
```

El json siempre sera asi y tendra el objeto  pero el primer objeto como ven que dice `cargo, grupo o files` podrian ser otros mas y lo que necesito es obtener la palabra que esta en esa posición.

Intento Logica:

```
 import org.json.JSONObject; // Uso esta libreria

 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(request.getJson());
 // Aca obtendria el valor que de cargo pero no siempre sera cargo
 // Por esa razón quisiera tener el nombre del objeto que tiene el array 
 String value = json.toMap().get("cargo").toString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener los valores dentro del Mapa que obtienes en `json.toMap()` puedes iterarlo, este ejemplo funcionaria asumiendo que el array de valores siempre serán String y que la estructura sera la misma.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{\"files\":[{\"tipo\":\"zip\",\"dt\":\"4010\",\"id\":\"35\",\"grup\":\"015\"}]}");

    String nombre = null;
    Map<String, String> valores = null;

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> object : json.toMap().entrySet()) {
        // Nombre del objeto
        nombre = object.getKey();
        // Inicialmente el objeto es una lista que tiene un Map.
        valores = getMap(object.getValue());
    }

    System.out.println(nombre);
    System.out.println(valores);
    //Metodo para imprimir valores utilizando un for.
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> variable : valores.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(variable.getKey() + ":" + variable.getValue());
    }
}

// Método para extraer el Mapa con los valores dentro de la lista inicial.
public static Map<String, String> getMap(Object valores) {
    if (valores instanceof List) {
        List<Object> lista = (List<Object>) valores;

        if (lista.size() == 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("La lista no tiene valores");
        }
        if (lista.size() > 1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("La lista tiene más de un grupo de valores");
        }

        return (Map<String, String>) lista.get(0);

    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("El objeto no es una lista");
    }
}



Ejemplo de Ejecución:

files
{dt=4010, tipo=zip, grup=015, id=35}
dt:4010
tipo:zip
grup:015
id:35
```